# Conditionally hide column in v-data-table (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` with the `actions` column and I want to show this column only if user has some permission. I'm using mixin to check the permissions

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```html
<template v-slot:[`header.actions`]="{ header }" v-if="hasPermission('update center')">
  {{ header.text }}
</template>
```

This is how I'm using mixin in component file:

```js
import BaseLayout from "../layouts/Base/Base.vue";
import hasPermission from "../../../mixins/hasPermissions";
        
export default {
  mixins: [hasPermission],
...
}
```

Result:  [[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVSgJ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDTV6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header.actions` is a slot to override the rendering of `actions` column header. If you do not pass it down (when condition is `false`), Vuetify renders default representation.

If you want to conditionally hide (not render) certain column, make your headers `computed`

```js
computed: {
  headers() {
    const headers = [
      // other headers definitions
    ]
    if(this.hasPermission('update center')) {
      headers.push({
        // actions header definition
      })
    }

    return headers
  }
}
```